# displaying topological sort/linear extensions via labeled Hasse diagrams

Tags: graphs-and-networks, packages

Is there a Mathematica implementation/package that *displays* all topological sorts (i.e. linear extensions) of a partial order using labelled Hasse diagrams (nodes labeled with the appropriate topological sort values)?

For instance, consider the partial order determined by the pairs (a,c), (b,c) (two independent elements a and b, with a maximum c above it in the Hasse diagram). Is there a package to display the two topological sorts (linear extensions) using the numbers 1, 2, 3 via labeled Hasse Diagrams? In the first labeled Hasse Diagram, the node a is labeled with 1, b with 2 and c with 3. In the second labeled Hasse diagram, the node a is labeled with 2, b with 1 and c with 3. The Hasse diagram is displayed as a "hat"-shaped (^) graph, with labels.

I would need code that is adaptable to move labels around via various operations. So a proprietary package from Mathematica for which code is not accessible would not help.

ETA picture below regards one of the answers given below in the comments.

TransitiveReductionGraph[Graph[{b, a, c}, {a -> c, b -> c}],   VertexLabels -> Placed[{"Name", "Index"}, {Before, After}]]

No longer displays as before. Is there a reason for this? The new result is:

[image]

Comment: Maybe something like `Graph[{hasseData}, 
 GraphLayout -> {"LayeredEmbedding", "Orientation" -> Bottom}]`  Something to work with would better attract help.

Comment: `TransitiveReductionGraph[Graph[{b, a, c}, {a -> c, b -> c}], 
 VertexLabels -> Placed[{"Name", "Index"}, {Before, After}]]` and `TransitiveReductionGraph[Graph[{a, b, c}, {a -> c, b -> c}], 
 VertexLabels -> Placed[{"Name", "Index"}, {Before, After}]]`?

Comment: Thanks kglr. Could this be adapted to display all permutations of labels 1 through 3 on the vertices?

Comment: Mike, the vertex indices are assigned based on the ordering of the vertex list. So you can use any permutation of `{a,b,c}` as the first argument in `Graph[...]` to assign desired indices to the vertices.

Comment: @kglr Odd, when I execute the code TransitiveReductionGraph[Graph[{b, a, c}, {a -> c, b -> c}],   VertexLabels -> Placed[{"Name", "Index"}, {Before, After}]] it no longer displays matters as before. I get a set of sets at node 1 {{8},{5,9},{6,7,10}}, a matrix at node 2 (first row: 1 2, second row: 3 4) and c at node 3. Did something change?

Comment: Try `ClearAll[a,b,c]` before `TransitiveReductionGraph[...]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
edges =  {a -> c, b -> c};

TransitiveReductionGraph[Graph[#, edges],   
    VertexLabels -> Placed[{"Name", "Index"}, {Before, After}], 
    GraphLayout -> {"LayeredEmbedding", "Orientation" -> Top}, 
    PlotLabel -> Row[{"VertexList: ", #}]] & /@ 
  Permutations[{a, b, c}] // Multicolumn[#, 3] &
```

[image]